# How to iterate a list of string parameters with API calls?

Tags: python, list, loops, iterator

I am trying to lookup a list of applications result thru API calls.

I ran into issue that I need to pass the application id as a string parameter and instead of passing it one at a time, I would like to **iterate all IDs at once**.

This is sample code on how to lookup one application_id

```
result = lookup_api.list(application_id = "{{APP_ID}}"" 

if result['status'] == 200:
    print(result['data'])
else:
    print("An error occurred." + str(result['status']))
    print(result['data'])
```

If I have a list of Application IDs, i.e.,

```
app_id=['10000001','10000002','10000003','10000004']
```

I'd like to iterate all application ids (as string) in the lookup_api.list, any idea on how to achieve this?

I tried

```
index = 0
while index < len(app_id):
        result = [lookup_api.list(application_id=app_id[i]) for i in range(len(app_id))]
        index += 1
    
    if result['status'] == 200:
        print(result['data'])
    else:
        print("An error occurred." + str(result['status']))
        print(result['data'])
```

But it isn't iterating my application list. And I got **"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"** on if result['status'] == 200.

Thank you in advance for your help here!

Comment: for i in range(len(app_id)):
    result = lookup_api.list(application_id=app_id[i])

Comment: I changed it to the above query, now I'm able to pull the result but it's only showing me the last application in my list, any idea on how to get all of the application ids?

Comment: You might want to look into python list comprehension: `result = [ lookup_api.list(application_id=app_id[i]) for i in range(len(app_id)) ]`

Comment: @etherealyn thanks! I just tested with list comprehension, but it returned another erros msg saying "list indices must be integers or slices, not str", any idea why? ty in advanced for your help.

Comment: This is because you are iterating over a list of strings and using them as indices, which is not allowed. Perhaps, try using application id directly like: `result = [lookup_api.list(application_id=x) for x in app_id]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235520/discussion-between-gfchqz-and-etherealyn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the list and use list comprehension to collect the results from API calls as follows:

```py
results = [lookup_api.list(application_id=x) for x in app_id]

for result in results:
   if result['status'] == 200:
      print(result['data'])
   else:
      print("An error occurred." + str(result['status']))
   print(result['data'])
```